# Spark saveAsTextFile Tab Delimited in Python

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

Hello I just want to know how to saveAsTextFile in Spark Python without brackets and tab delimited.
Example

```
  ('123', 2),('345', 3),('567', 9) to a file-> 
    123   2
    345   3
    567   9
```

I know there is a way using C style printing like: (%c'\t'%i, (v1, v2))

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the answer must be also with \n 123 2\n 345 3\n 567 9\n

Comment: You can always do mapping before saveAsTextFile to have tab delimited lines.

Comment: Do you have any code example??? Thanks in advance!!! sorry i am very new to spark

Comment: format=output.map(lambda (user, cnt): "{0},{1}".format(user, cnt)).saveAsTextFile(Path)

Comment: but it give me an error....

Comment: and what is the error ?

Comment: i lost the log, but it was regarding the listener.... nothing related to the code.... i was able to use that code in a python script and worked....

Comment: @JR Martinez posted my answer with sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a mapping to have them tab delimited, then you can easily use `saveAsTextFile` method as in the example below.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('123', 2),('345', 3),('567', 9)])
rdd.map(lambda x: "%s\t%s" %(x[0],x[1])).saveAsTextFile("output")
```

Comment: That worked AWESOME!!!! Thanks! I have been looking for this for a long time now... and there is almost nothing about formatting files in Spark Python on the internet, "Google"....

Answer (score 0):

This one work also:

`>>> rdd.map(lambda (k, v): "{0},{1}".format(k, v)).saveAsTextFile("path")`

Answer (score 0):

If you use SPARK DataFrame you could use the writes formats like so:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('123', 2),('345', 3),('567', 9)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
rdd.write.csv(path='output_dir', sep='\t')
```

Where the variable `spark` is your `pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession`.